# Software for calculating simplicial homology (over the integers)

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, math-software

I am interested in looking for a software package that can calculate the homology of simplicial complexes over the integers.

(Ideally, written in a "popular" language such as Python, Matlab, etc. I am not concerned about efficiency, any working code will do.)

There are quite a few software that calculate over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coefficients, due to recent popularity in topological data analysis. However, I am mainly interested in $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients.

Any recommendations will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!